# Css margin-left not executed if jQuery change it

Tags: jquery, css, html, margin

Strange behavior of my CSS which is:

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #DivWraper {
        margin-left: 250px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in page, I have this JS code:

```
function sidebarClose() {
    $("#DivWraper").attr("style", "margin-left: 0px");
}

function sidebarOpen() {
    if (this.window.innerWidth > 800) {
        $("#DivWraper").attr("style", "margin-left: 250px");
    }
}
```

If we call `sidebarClose()` and `sidebarOpen()`, then the CSS behaviour doesn't work anymore.

If I comments these 2 lines `$("#DivWraper").attr(...)`, then the CSS keeps on working. Why do `$("#DivWraper").attr(...)` prevent the CSS from working?

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#DivWraper").css('marginLeft', '250px');` ?

Comment: It seems to be the expected behaviour. JS/jQuery always overwrites css. There is nothing strange about it.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the jQuery part doesn't work. Ignore what I wrote

Comment: Dou you have a default #DivWraper css (outside @media selector) ? What effect are you expecting with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your use of `this.window.innerWidth`. `window` is a global, so you should remove `this.`:

```
function sidebarOpen() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        $("#DivWraper").attr("style", "margin-left:250px");
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qmeand9b/)

Also note that your use of `attr()` to set inline styles is not ideal. You could use `css()`, but even that doesn't follow best practice. A better solution would be to set a class on the element. This way you don't even need to check the width of the window as the media query will take care of that for you:

```js
$('#open').click(sidebarOpen);
$('#close').click(sidebarClose);

function sidebarOpen() {
  $("#DivWraper").addClass("open");
}

function sidebarClose() {
  $("#DivWraper").removeClass("open");
}
```

```css
#DivWraper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
@media (min-width: 200px) { /* required to make this snippet work, use 800px in production */
  #DivWraper {
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  #DivWraper.open {
    margin-left: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivWraper" class="open"></div>

<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
```

Note that I amended the width in the media query of the snipper to `200px` so that it works there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jqymu5vy/ If you move the frame to get less than 600px, the margin-left box will go to 0px. http://www.cjoint.com/doc/16_12/FLpopdjCwKc_DivWrapperMarginLeft.jpg. But if you play with "Open" and "Close" buttons before reducing the frame size, then the margin-left box will not go to 0px.

Comment: That's right - because you've set the `attr()` of the elements regardless of the window width. If you use the improved version of your logic which I outlined in the snippet you won't have that issue

Answer (score 0):

Think it's because you're trying to override the CSS style which is defined by id "#DivWrapper" using the style attribute of the element. Think would be better to either only defined "margin-left" in the style attribute or instead use css classes and replace the class in your methods.

CSS:

```
.sidebarOpen
{
        margin-left: 250px;
        transition: 0.5s;
}
.sidebarClose
{
        margin-left: 0px;
        transition: 0.5s;
}
```

JS:

```
function sidebarClose() {
    $("#DivWraper").attr("class", "sidebarClose");
}


function sidebarOpen() {
    if(this.window.innerWidth > 800) {
        $("#DivWraper").attr("class", "sidebarOpen");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery apply inline style to the element so they get more specificity than CSS code. If you apply `!important` (Not recommended) after margin in CSS it will override the jQuery style.

Use a class `.open` which defines margin left and add it via jQuery.

```
function sidebarClose() {
    $("#DivWraper").addClass("open");
}


function sidebarOpen() {
    if(this.window.innerWidth > 800) {
      $("#DivWraper").removeClass("open");
    }
}
```